# calculate difference in seconds between two columns with spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I am using spark sql in scala to calculate the diff between two columns

```
writingTime,time
 2020-06-25T13:29:34.415Z,2020-06-25T13:29:33.190Z
```

I am expecting the difference between these two columns to be 1 second.

I used the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("path")
val diff_secs_col = col("time").cast("long") - col("writingTime").cast("long")
val resultDf = df.withColumn("date_diff_seconds", datediff(col("writingTime"), col("time"))).show()
```

Any help with this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```scala
 val resultDf = df.withColumn("date_diff_seconds",
      $"writingTime".cast("timestamp").cast("long") -  $"time".cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    resultDf.show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------------+------------------------+---+
      * |writingTime             |time                    |date_diff_seconds  |
      * +------------------------+------------------------+---+
      * |2020-06-25T13:29:34.415Z|2020-06-25T13:29:33.190Z|1  |
      * +------------------------+------------------------+---+
      */

.show(false)
```